# Using 60A Relay on 30A DC Circuit

Tags: relay

I have a **Starter Kill Switch**, and it's using 30A relay.
It worked well with 7-10Amp current in my previous car.

Got another car, and the circuit where I need to insert the relay - is now 30A.

In order to avoid 30A Relay working on it's limits in a 30Amp circuit =>

**1)** Is it a good idea to replace 30A relay with 60A relay ?

**2)** Will 60A relay function well in 30A circuit?

UPDATE:
Relay DataSheet - https://www.msrelay.com/uploads/soft/cars/MAH.pdf

[image]
[image]

Comment: A rating is a rating. If you know your peak current is really 30 A, then something that stands that current works. You will have to read the datasheet of your switch/relay module. It will state how much current under which conditions for how long is OK. We know none of that, you have all the data.

Comment: @whoever_voted_to_close because "needs details or clarity" : could you please explain what is unclear (for me it's clear), or what additional detail you think would be useful AND you expect OP to be able to find out (true, a full current waveform would have been useful to choose a minimalist relay, but I strongly doubt OP is equipped to measure it, and the question can be answered without this information). If there is a missing piece of information, please just ask instead of voting to close.

Comment: Well [here](https://www.msrelay.com/uploads/soft/cars/MAH.pdf) is its datasheet.  Loads listed are "resistive", "flasher", and "lamp"; nothing inductive.  We don't even know if this would be switching an inductive load.

Comment: What is the basis for claiming a starter solenoid takes 60A?  That sounds rather high.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you don't know exactly the requirements, then I think over-sizing the relay is probably the easiest way to be on the safe side (as long as you don't care too much about price and volume).

Having a relay rated for 60A in a 30A circuit is very unlikely to be worse than a 30A relay (the current rating is just a maximum current), provided the other parameters are similar (for example, check that the 60A relay isn't requiring too much current for the coil).

Also, check that your relay is rated for DC current (some relays are rated only for AC, or far lower for DC, because braking the electric arc when opening is far easier in AC)

Comment: thanks for the answer! as rdtsc indicated, there is the datasheet https://www.msrelay.com/uploads/soft/cars/MAH.pdf
Based on this, do you think the coil current (trigger) on 60A Relay is same as on 30A Relay?